# How to check and replace special character(\) contain in a String in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String `str=p2\7\2010` I want to check and replace if `str.contains("\")` then replace it into this`("\\\\")` instead of `\`. i am unable to do this in Java please give your little effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [String.replace()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
if (str.contains("\\")) {
    str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
}
```

You can also use `String.replaceAll()`, but it uses regular expressions and so is slower in such trivial case.

**UPDATE:**

Implementation of `String.replace()` is based on regular expressions as well, but compiled in [Pattern.LITERAL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL) mode.

Comment: ho do i check,Is str contain \

Comment: @subodh: `if (str.contains("\\"))` will check if `str` contains `\`. But it's redundant. You can just call `str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");` You will end up with (copy of) original string in case there is nothing to replace.

Comment: @dacwe: You are right. This is why I added comment about that. However author explicitly asked "I want to check and replace" so I provided code with the check.

Comment: Thanks: But while doing str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\"); it will produce as "p20" p2 and junk not readable format

Comment: @subodh: please specify what exactly do you need. I don't get what's the problem with p20.

Comment: @Michał Šrajer: My String is str="p2\7\2010", and i need as str="p2\\\\7\\\\2010". may be str="p2\7" then i need str="p2\\\\7" and if it's str="\" then str="\\\\".

Comment: @Michał Šrajer: Thanks, I got the solution as  if(str.indexOf("\\")!=-1) {
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
    }

Answer (score 0):

`str.contains("\"")` matches string that have a " in them.

What you probably want is `str.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\")`

Additionally; for checking if it contains a \ you'd need `str.contains("\\")`, since the \ is a special character it has to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String newString = oldString.replace("/", "//");
```

or try pattern method,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/"); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abc/xyz"); 
String output = matcher.replaceAll("//");
```